# Create Random List of List with the first element sublist repeat n times

Tags: python

Please help me to create a list of 329 elements from random number 0..9 and repeat time per elements as list:`list = [18, 70, 56, 30, 24, 18, 28, 54, 21, 10]`, each element is a list

```
ret = []
for i in range(329):
    new = []
```

Comment: Repeat time per element as list, can you clarify this?

Comment: can you please introduce an example of what is your expected result?

Comment: For example, number 0 repeats 18 times, 1 repeats 70 times... please noted that 329 = sum of elements in list

Comment: the expected result is `[[0],[5],[8]...[5]]`

Comment: according to u 5 repeats 70 times? so thats 350 there itself

Comment: @KháiDuy please explain , u want to know how many times each element exits???

Comment: Hi Inder, I want to create a list, like that `[[0],[5],[8]...[5]]` value only 0...9, and the value repeat n times as the `list = [18, 70, 56, 30, 24, 18, 28, 54, 21, 10]`, for example, 0 is 18 times, 1 is 70 times... 9 is 10 times

Comment: okay  got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, suppose you have a list with number frequencies:

```
lst = [18, 70, 56, 30, 24, 18, 28, 54, 21, 10]
```

you can simply generate your `ret` list with

```
ret = [k for k, freq in enumerate(lst) for i in range(freq)]
```

so it contains 18 zeros, 70 ones and so on ... and simply shuffle it:

```
import random
random.shuffle(ret)
```

**EDIT**

A simple example with a smaller set:

```
>>> import random
>>> lst = [2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
>>> ret = [k for k, freq in enumerate(lst) for i in range(freq)]
>>> ret
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9]
>>> random.shuffle(ret)
>>> ret
[1, 0, 1, 4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 3, 6, 4, 6, 0, 2, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you for your support, but can I start with
`for i in range(329):` cause the `new` contain not only this, I still have other index

Comment: @KháiDuy, you can first create `ret` list and then use it in your `for` loop with `ret[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing, but is this what you want?

```
my_list = [18, 70, 56, 30, 24, 18, 28, 54, 21, 10]
new_list = []

for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
    for v in range(x):
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

P.D - It's bad practice to use reserved names (list) in your code.

Comment: Yes you can, using randint. See my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

**As per your comment to my first answer**, here is the same but using a random number between 0-9.

```
from random import randint

my_list = [18, 70, 56, 30, 24, 18, 28, 54, 21, 10]
new_list = []

#Loop through each element in my_list
for x in my_list:
    #Create looping range from value of element
    for v in range(x):
        #Append a random number between 0-9 to new_list
        new_list.append(randint(0, 9))
```

Comment: It simply creates a list of 329 random numbers ignoring the content of `my_list`

Comment: @taras - I thought that's what he asked for? And it doesn't ignore the contents of  my_list, it uses each element to define the amount of iterations performed when appending the random number to the new_list

Comment: @Nordle, apparently `my_list` contain digit frequency in the resulting list

Comment: @taras - my first answer addressed the issue but he then asked for the resulting list to be random as opposed to 0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2.. etc

Comment: I am sorry for making confusion, but the result of @taras is correct, but I need it in that kind `[[0],[5],[8]...[5]]` with the opening `for i in range(329):` because I will add more code to get the final list like this `[[1,2,8,4],[5,3,4,7]....[9,5,9,1]]`

Comment: @Nordle, You can fix your answer by replacing `randint(1, 9)` with `randint(0, x)`

Comment: @Nordle, Sorry, my mistake, randint(0, x) is not correct way of doing it.

Comment: @taras - although it should be starting the random int at 0 and not 1, so thanks for that!